# bitwise checking if a number is -1 or not

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have to make a function that check if a input number is -1 or not. here's the requirement

```
isTmin - returns 1 if x is the minimum, two's complement number, and 0 otherwise 
Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | +
Max ops: 10
Rating: 1
```

First I try this:

```
int isTmin(int x) {
  return !(x^(0x01<<31));
}
```

this method works, but I am not allowed to use the shifting operator. any ideas how can I solve this problem w/o using shift operator?

Comment: So 1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, etc. in binary are all '-1'?

Comment: ah, I forgot to mention it. it's 32bit int. so, only 0x80000000

Comment: if you do a bitwise not then all the ones will becone zeroes, then the number will just be `0`

Comment: the value -1 in 32-bit 2's complement is 0xFFFFFFFF, not 0x80000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int isTmin(unsigned x) {
    return !x ^ !(x+x);
}
```

Note that you need to use `unsigned` in C to get twos-complement math and proper wrapping -- with `int` its implemention/undefined.

Comment: `!(x ^ 0xffffffff)` is enough

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc:  Two issues:  a) That checks for -1, not the minimum 2s complement number (not really clear what the OP wants) b) It only works for exactly 32-bit `unsigned` (which the OP didn't originally specify)

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing it needs to check is if it's 0xffff ffff, then:

```
return x^0xffffffff == 0
```

This is only true if x is also `0xffffffff`.

Comment: 0xffffffff is -1 -- the poster wants INT_MIN -- the most negative signed number.

Comment: he did say -1 in his summary, but the ACTUAL requirement he quoted is completely different.  I believe he wants what the quote says and not what he *thinks* it says.